# How to animate the projected world population growth with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I made a plot of the projected world population that I've been struggling for days to animate.
Here is the plot:

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from celluloid import Camera

dataDict = {'Year': {0: 1950,
  1: 1951,
  2: 1952,
  3: 1953,
  4: 1954,
  5: 1955,
  6: 1956,
  7: 1957,
  8: 1958,
  9: 1959,
  10: 1960,
  11: 1961,
  12: 1962,
  13: 1963,
  14: 1964,
  15: 1965,
  16: 1966,
  17: 1967,
  18: 1968,
  19: 1969,
  20: 1970,
  21: 1971,
  22: 1972,
  23: 1973,
  24: 1974,
  25: 1975,
  26: 1976,
  27: 1977,
  28: 1978,
  29: 1979,
  30: 1980,
  31: 1981,
  32: 1982,
  33: 1983,
  34: 1984,
  35: 1985,
  36: 1986,
  37: 1987,
  38: 1988,
  39: 1989,
  40: 1990,
  41: 1991,
  42: 1992,
  43: 1993,
  44: 1994,
  45: 1995,
  46: 1996,
  47: 1997,
  48: 1998,
  49: 1999,
  50: 2000,
  51: 2001,
  52: 2002,
  53: 2003,
  54: 2004,
  55: 2005,
  56: 2006,
  57: 2007,
  58: 2008,
  59: 2009,
  60: 2010,
  61: 2011,
  62: 2012,
  63: 2013,
  64: 2014,
  65: 2015,
  66: 2016,
  67: 2017,
  68: 2018,
  69: 2019,
  70: 2020,
  71: 2091,
  72: 2092,
  73: 2093,
  74: 2094,
  75: 2095,
  76: 2096,
  77: 2097,
  78: 2098,
  79: 2099,
  80: 2100},
 'billion': {0: 2.5,
  1: 2.6,
  2: 2.6,
  3: 2.7,
  4: 2.7,
  5: 2.8,
  6: 2.8,
  7: 2.9,
  8: 2.9,
  9: 3.0,
  10: 3.0,
  11: 3.1,
  12: 3.2,
  13: 3.2,
  14: 3.3,
  15: 3.3,
  16: 3.4,
  17: 3.5,
  18: 3.6,
  19: 3.6,
  20: 3.7,
  21: 3.8,
  22: 3.9,
  23: 3.9,
  24: 4.0,
  25: 4.1,
  26: 4.2,
  27: 4.2,
  28: 4.3,
  29: 4.4,
  30: 4.5,
  31: 4.5,
  32: 4.6,
  33: 4.7,
  34: 4.8,
  35: 4.9,
  36: 5.0,
  37: 5.1,
  38: 5.1,
  39: 5.2,
  40: 5.3,
  41: 5.4,
  42: 5.5,
  43: 5.6,
  44: 5.7,
  45: 5.7,
  46: 5.8,
  47: 5.9,
  48: 6.0,
  49: 6.1,
  50: 6.1,
  51: 6.2,
  52: 6.3,
  53: 6.4,
  54: 6.5,
  55: 6.5,
  56: 6.6,
  57: 6.7,
  58: 6.8,
  59: 6.9,
  60: 7.0,
  61: 7.0,
  62: 7.1,
  63: 7.2,
  64: 7.3,
  65: 7.4,
  66: 7.5,
  67: 7.5,
  68: 7.6,
  69: 7.7,
  70: 7.8,
  71: 10.8,
  72: 10.8,
  73: 10.8,
  74: 10.8,
  75: 10.9,
  76: 10.9,
  77: 10.9,
  78: 10.9,
  79: 10.9,
  80: 10.9}}
df = pd.DataFrame(dataDict)

#Plotting
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
sns.lineplot(x='Year',y='billion',data=df,ax=ax,color='b')
ax.set_ylim([2,11])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax.margins(x=0, tight=True) # zero padding for the x-axis```
plt.fill_between(df['Year'], df['billion'], color='darkgreen', where=df['Year'] <= 2019)
plt.fill_between(df['Year'], df['billion'], color='lightgreen', where=df['Year'] >= 2019)
marked_years = [1950, 1987, 2019, 2050]
ax.scatter(marked_years, np.interp(marked_years, df['Year'], df['billion']), marker='o', color='black', s=50)


plt.text(1950,2.7,'2.5 Billion\nin 1950',horizontalalignment='right')
plt.text(1987,5.3,'5.1 Billion\nin 1987',horizontalalignment='right')
plt.text(2019,8,'7.7 Billion\nin 2019',horizontalalignment='right')
plt.text(2050,9.3,'9.7 Billion\nin 2050',horizontalalignment='right',color='r')

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)#hiding y spine
plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False) #hiding y axis
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.savefig('worldPopulationGrowth_by2050.png',dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
plt.close()
````

I tried to use the sinus example from matplotlib documentation (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html).
I was able to just animate the lineplot, but not fill_between color with the following code:

```
#Tentative of animation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
x = df['Year']
y = df['billion']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y, color='b')
#plt.fill_between(df['Year'], df['billion'], color='darkgreen', where=df['Year'] <= 2019)
#plt.fill_between(df['Year'], df['billion'], color='lightgreen', where=df['Year'] >= 2019)

def update(num, x, y, line):
    line.set_data(x[:num], y[:num])  
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line],
                              interval=15, blit=True)
ani.save('populationAnimated.gif')
plt.show()
```

So I am seeking for your helpful assistance to animate the initial plot with the green fill between color. Thank you in advance for your time and sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence of patches are stored in `collections`. Everytime update is called a new patch is added. Therefore, you will need to clear previous patches as implemented here. Morever, you want to have `blit=False` because the `axes` are being modified.

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dataDict)
x = df['Year']
y = df['billion']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

line, = ax.plot(x, y, color='b')

def update(num, x, y, line,ax):
    ax.collections.clear()
    line.set_data(x[:num], y[:num])
    ax.fill_between(df['Year'][:num], df['billion'][:num], color='darkgreen', where=df['Year'][:num] <= 2019)
    ax.fill_between(df['Year'][:num], df['billion'][:num], color='lightgreen', where=df['Year'][:num] > 2019)
    return line, ax

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line,ax],
                              interval=15, blit=False)
ani.save('populationAnimated.gif')
plt.show()
```